# Ngnix ingress controller for aks using internal loadbalancer

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, azure-aks

showing internal loadbalancer external IP is in pending, could someone help me on this issue to resolve

```
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace=ingress-private --set rbac.create=true --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP="10.0.0.0" --set controller.replicaCount=2 --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io\/os"=linux --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"="true"
```

```
NAME: nginx-ingress
LAST DEPLOYED: Mon May  3 15:39:02 2021
NAMESPACE: ingress-private
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
NOTES:
The ingress-nginx controller has been installed.
It may take a few minutes for the LoadBalancer IP to be available.
You can watch the status by running 'kubectl --namespace ingress-private get services -o wide -w nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller'
```

```
kubectl get svc -n ingress-private -w
NAME                                               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.0.0.0    <pending>     80:32392/TCP,443:32499/TCP   3m2s
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.0.0.223   <none>        443/TCP                      3m2s
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Azure [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-faq#are-there-any-restrictions-on-using-ip-addresses-within-these-subnets), you can't use `10.0.0.0` IP address. Try using a different address. I am assuming you are trying to execute this [scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb#specify-an-ip-address). Check the service details for any error information.

```
kubectl describe svc -n ingress-private nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller
```

Ref:

> Are there any restrictions on using IP addresses within these subnets?
>
> Yes. Azure reserves 5 IP addresses within each subnet. These are
> x.x.x.0-x.x.x.3 and the last address of the subnet. x.x.x.1-x.x.x.3 is
> reserved in each subnet for Azure services.
>
> - x.x.x.0: Network address
> - x.x.x.1: Reserved by Azure for the default gateway
> - x.x.x.2, x.x.x.3: Reserved by Azure to map the Azure DNS IPs to the VNet space
> - x.x.x.255: Network broadcast address

Answer (score 0):

Below is the service details

```
C:\Users\av13\Music\spoke-terraform-updated\kubernetes-nexus>kubectl describe svc -n ingress-private nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller
Name:                     nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller
Namespace:                ingress-private
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
                          app.kubernetes.io/instance=nginx-ingress
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
                          app.kubernetes.io/version=0.46.0
                          helm.sh/chart=ingress-nginx-3.30.0
Annotations:              meta.helm.sh/release-name: nginx-ingress
                          meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: ingress-private
                          service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: true
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=nginx-ingress,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.0.188.67
IP:                       10.145.72.102
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               http/TCP
NodePort:                 http  32392/TCP
Endpoints:                10.145.72.50:80,10.145.72.94:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               https/TCP
NodePort:                 https  32499/TCP
Endpoints:                10.145.72.50:443,10.145.72.94:443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age                  From                Message
  ----    ------                ----                 ----                -------
  Normal  EnsuringLoadBalancer  78s (x278 over 22h)  service-controller  Ensuring load balancer
```

still external IP is in pending state

```
C:\Users\av13\Music\spoke-terraform-updated\kubernetes-nexus>kubectl get svc -n ingress-private -w
NAME                                               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.0.188.67    <pending>     80:32392/TCP,443:32499/TCP   22h
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.0.159.223   <none>        443/TCP                      22h
```